# Default Printer keep changing in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, printing, printer, network-printer

I am facing a issue in windows 7 enterprise edition for default printer settings. The windows 7 machines are virtual machines and i connect it via remote desktop connection. I need the default printer to be Adobe PDF every time and its already set as default printer. Whenever my application prints a document to any printer on a network, where printer name is passed via code. The recently used printer becomes the default printer in windows 7. This issue did not occur earlier in windows XP machines. As this is a enterprise edition there is no option for "Manage Default printer" . Is there any other way the adobe pdf printer be always set as default printer,like registry changes etc. The last option would be to achieve it thru code changes, but the application is perfectly running fine in win XP. Let me know for any information Need your help. 
Thanks

Comment: I am running on a Windows 7 Enterprise desktop, and I am able to set my default printer, I don't believe the reason "Manage Default Printer" is missing is because of the OS your using.

Comment: i am also able to set the default printer, but when my application(VBA) uses a printer on a network for printing, that printer will become the default automatically. What i want is to keep the Adobe PDF printer to default every time. So i was looking for the "Manage Default Printer" option where there is a option (first radio button) to keep the default printer static. But there isn't any option. So i searched for any registry option but din't get one.